# What is this date and time format?

Tags: c#, c++, sharepoint, time, format

I was wondering if anyone knows this time-format:

- the value *635872032000000000* represents the 01.Jan 2016.
- the value *636502752000000000* represents the 31.Dec 2017.

I googled the value and found, that sharepoint is taking this as a parameter too.

Does someone know the format, how to use it or where it's from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These dates are represented in *ticks*:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx

> ticks 
>   Type: System.Int64
>
> A date and time expressed in the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at
>   00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

e.g. C# code

```
  long value = 635872032000000000L;

  DateTime result = new DateTime(value);

  Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! :D